# Client-side react - error after adding movies to favourite and no such user after update password

Tags: reactjs

I am a student learning full-stack.

I am trying to build client-side of an app using React with existing server-side code (REST API and database) .

Currently, trying to create a profile view and allowing users to add/remove movies from favourite. There's movie-card.jsx and movie-view.jsx.

I'm trying to allow user to add/remove movies from user profile under movie-view.

Now user able to add/remove movies. But the problem is after clicking add/remove movies and click go to profile, the error appears. If i refresh the page and go to profile, the favourite movies list is actually updated.

Another problem is, when updating profile for example, update password. Previously was hashedpassword, after updating, it became not encrypted which when i login after updating, it says no such user.

How do i avoid that?

Provided my github pull link from a new branch. movie api from my repo in github under movie_api2

https://github.com/joannawongww/myFlix-client/pull/4

movie-view.jsx

```js
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from "react";
import {
  MovieCard
} from "../movie-card/movie-card";
import {
  MovieView
} from "../movie-view/movie-view";
import {
  LoginView
} from "../login-view/login-view";
import {
  SignupView
} from "../signup-view/signup-view";
import {
  ProfileView
} from "../profile-view/profile-view";
import {
  NavigationBar
} from "../navigation-bar/navigation-bar";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import {
  Navbar,
  Container,
  Nav
} from "react-bootstrap";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Navigate
} from "react-router-dom";

export const MainView = () => {
  const storedUser = localStorage.getItem("user");
  const storedToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);

  const onLogout = () => {
    setUser(null);
    setToken(null);
    localStorage.clear();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!token) {
      return;
    }

    fetch("https://myflix-jwww-f51e9c501b1f.herokuapp.com/movies", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        },
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);

        const moviesFromApi = data.map((movie) => {
          return {
            id: movie._id,
            Title: movie.Title,
            Description: movie.Description,
            ImagePath: movie.ImagePath,
            Genre: movie.Genre.Name,
            Director: movie.Director.Name,
            Featured: movie.Featured.toString(),
          };
        });
        setMovies(moviesFromApi);
      });
  }, [token]);

  return ( <
    BrowserRouter >
    <
    NavigationBar user = {
      user
    }
    onLoggedOut = {
      () => {
        setUser(null);
      }
    }
    /> <
    Row className = "justify-content-md-center" >
    <
    Routes >
    <
    Route path = "/signup"
    element = { <
      > {
        user ? ( <
          Navigate to = "/" / >
        ) : ( <
          Col md = {
            5
          } >
          <
          SignupView / >
          <
          /Col>
        )
      } <
      />
    }
    />

    <
    Route path = "/login"
    element = { <
      > {
        user ? ( <
          Navigate to = "/" / >
        ) : ( <
          Col md = {
            5
          } >
          <
          LoginView onLoggedIn = {
            (user, token) => {
              setUser(user);
              setToken(token);
            }
          }
          /> <
          /Col>
        )
      } <
      />
    }
    />

    <
    Route path = "/profile"
    element = { <
      > {!user ? ( <
          Navigate to = "/login"
          replace / >
        ) : ( <
          Col >
          <
          ProfileView user = {
            user
          }
          token = {
            token
          }
          setUser = {
            setUser
          }
          movies = {
            movies
          }
          onLogout = {
            onLogout
          }
          /> <
          /Col>
        )
      } <
      />
    }
    />

    <
    Route path = "/movies/:movieId"
    element = { <
      > {!user ? ( <
          Navigate to = "/login"
          replace / >
        ) : movies.length === 0 ? ( <
          Col > List is empty! < /Col>
        ) : ( <
          Col md = {
            8
          } >
          <
          MovieView movies = {
            movies
          }
          user = {
            user
          }
          setUser = {
            setUser
          }
          token = {
            token
          }
          /> <
          /Col>
        )
      } <
      />
    }
    />

    <
    Route path = "/"
    element = { <
      > {!user ? ( <
          Navigate to = "/login"
          replace / >
        ) : movies.length === 0 ? ( <
          Col > List is empty! < /Col>
        ) : ( <
          > {
            movies.map((movie) => ( <
              Col className = "mb-4"
              key = {
                movie.id
              }
              md = {
                3
              } >
              <
              MovieCard movie = {
                movie
              }
              /> <
              /Col>
            ))
          } <
          />
        )
      } <
      />
    }
    /> <
    /Routes> <
    /Row> <
    /BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

movie-view.jsx

```js
import {
  useEffect,
  useState
} from "react";
import {
  useParams
} from "react-router";
import {
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import "./movie-view.scss";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import {
  ProfileView
} from "../profile-view/profile-view";

export const MovieView = ({
  user,
  token,
  movies,
  setUser
}) => {
  const {
    movieId
  } = useParams();
  const [Favorite, setFavorite] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user ? .Favorite ? .length && movieId) {
      setFavorite(user.Favorite.includes(movieId));
    }
    // const isFavorited = user.Favorite.includes(movieId);
    // setFavorite(isFavorited);
  }, [user.Favorite, movieId]);

  const addFavorite = () => {
    fetch(
        `https://myflix-jwww-f51e9c501b1f.herokuapp.com/users/${user.Username}/movies/${movieId}`, {
          method: "PUT",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setFavorite(true);
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(data));
        setUser(data);
      });
  };

  const removeFavorite = () => {
    fetch(
        `https://myflix-jwww-f51e9c501b1f.herokuapp.com/users/${user.Username}/movies/${movieId}`, {
          method: "DELETE",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setFavorite(false);
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(data));
        setUser(data);
      });
  };

  const movie = movies.find((movie) => movie.id === movieId);

  return ( <
    div >
    <
    div >
    <
    span >
    <
    img src = {
      movie.ImagePath
    }
    width = "30%" / >
    <
    /span> <
    /div>

    <
    div >
    <
    span > Title: < /span> <
    span > {
      movie.Title
    } < /span> <
    /div>

    <
    div >
    <
    span > Description: < /span> <
    span > {
      movie.Description
    } < /span> <
    /div>

    <
    div >
    <
    span > Genre: < /span> <
    span > {
      movie.Genre
    } < /span> <
    /div>

    <
    div >
    <
    span > Director: < /span> <
    span > {
      movie.Director
    } < /span> <
    /div>

    <
    div >
    <
    span > Featured: < /span> <
    span > {
      movie.Featured
    } < /span> <
    /div>

    {
      Favorite ? ( <
        Button onClick = {
          removeFavorite
        } > Remove from favourite movies < /Button>
      ) : ( <
        Button onClick = {
          addFavorite
        } > Add to my favorite movies < /Button>
      )
    }

    <
    Link to = {
      `/`
    } >
    <
    Button > Back < /Button> <
    /Link> <
    /div>
  );
};
```

profile-view.jsx

```js
import {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import {
  MovieCard
} from "../movie-card/movie-card";
import {
  ModalHeader
} from "react-bootstrap";
import {
  MovieView
} from "../movie-view/movie-view";

export const ProfileView = ({
  user,
  token,
  setUser,
  movies,
  onLogout
}) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState(user.Username);
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState(user.Email);
  const [birthday, setBirthday] = useState(user.Birthday);
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  const favoriteMovies = movies.filter((movie) => {
    return user.Favorite.includes(movie.id);
  });

  const handleShowModal = () => setShowModal(true);
  const handleCloseModal = () => setShowModal(false);

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const data = {
      Username: username,
      Password: password,
      Email: email,
      Birthday: birthday,
    };

    fetch(
        `https://myflix-jwww-f51e9c501b1f.herokuapp.com/users/${user.Username}`, {
          method: "PUT",
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json(), alert("Update successfully");
        } else {
          alert("Update failed");
        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(data));
        setUser(data);
      });
  };

  const handleDeleteUser = () => {
    fetch(
      `https://myflix-jwww-f51e9c501b1f.herokuapp.com/users/${user.Username}`, {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      }
    ).then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        onLogout();
      } else {
        alert("Something went wrong.");
      }
    });
  };

  return ( <
    >
    <
    h1 > Profile < /h1> <
    Row >
    <
    Col >
    <
    h3 > Information < /h3> <
    div > Username: {
      user.Username
    } < /div> <
    div > Email: {
      user.Email
    } < /div> <
    /Col>

    <
    Col >
    <
    h3 > Update Profile < /h3> <
    Form onSubmit = {
      handleSubmit
    } >
    <
    Form.Group controlId = "formUsername" >
    <
    Form.Label > Username: < /Form.Label> <
    Form.Control type = "text"
    value = {
      username
    }
    onChange = {
      (e) => setUsername(e.target.value)
    }
    required minLength = "5" /
    >
    <
    /Form.Group>

    <
    Form.Group controlId = "formPassword" >
    <
    Form.Label > Password: < /Form.Label> <
    Form.Control type = "password"
    value = {
      password
    }
    onChange = {
      (e) => setPassword(e.target.value)
    }
    required minLength = "8" /
    >
    <
    /Form.Group>

    <
    Form.Group controlId = "formEmail" >
    <
    Form.Label > Email: < /Form.Label> <
    Form.Control type = "email"
    value = {
      email
    }
    onChange = {
      (e) => setEmail(e.target.value)
    }
    required /
    >
    <
    /Form.Group>

    <
    Form.Group controlId = "formBirthday" >
    <
    Form.Label > Birthday: < /Form.Label> <
    Form.Control type = "date"
    value = {
      birthday
    }
    onChange = {
      (e) => setBirthday(e.target.value)
    }
    required /
    >
    <
    /Form.Group>

    <
    Button variant = "primary"
    type = "submit" >
    Update now <
    /Button> <
    /Form> <
    /Col> <
    /Row>

    <
    Row >
    <
    h3 > Favorite movies < /h3> {
      favoriteMovies.map((movie) => ( <
        Col key = {
          movie.id
        }
        md = {
          4
        } >
        <
        MovieCard movie = {
          movie
        } > < /MovieCard> <
        /Col>
      ))
    } <
    /Row>

    <
    Button variant = "primary"
    onClick = {
      handleShowModal
    } >
    Delete account <
    /Button> <
    Modal show = {
      showModal
    }
    onHide = {
      handleCloseModal
    } >
    <
    Modal.Header closeButton >
    <
    Modal.Title > Delete account < /Modal.Title> <
    /Modal.Header> <
    Modal.Body > Confirm delete account ? < /Modal.Body> <
    Modal.Footer >
    <
    button variant = "primary"
    onClick = {
      handleDeleteUser
    } >
    Yes <
    /button> <
    button variant = "secondary"
    onClick = {
      handleCloseModal
    } >
    No <
    /button> <
    /Modal.Footer> <
    /Modal> <
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you run prettier for the file. The jsx is not correctly formatted

Comment: alr run for the file.

Comment: And update the code in the question?